# localization isn't working (even with "-en" language files)

Tags: android, localization, android-emulator, android-drawable, android-resources

I have an android app which includes both English and Turkish(default) values and drawable files but my emulator only is working on the default one, which is Turkish now. (values and drawable-xxhdpi)

My emulator's settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iesHF.png

Here is my res folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZsGz.png

So what's the problem? Why doesn't it work on English files? I'm hopeless right now.

Comment: How are your string files named? And how are your strings named? The names must be exactly identical.

Comment: They are identical, i dont think thats the problem. I'll try to post those images as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I've written the file name wrong.
"drawable-en-xhpdi" -> "drawable-en-xhdpi" That didn't give any error.